# What causes a faulty Linear Voltage regulator to output wrong voltage

Tags: voltage-regulator, linear-regulator, fault

I made a circuit where I needed DC 8v supply. I was using a KA7808 to regulate the voltage. While testing the voltage regulator unit, I identified that the Regulator IC might be faulty because I was getting an output voltage of 4.8v - 4.9v for input voltage 18v. I am curious to know what might cause a voltage regulator IC to output wrong (not the rated) voltage. My assumption was, a faulty one would either passthrough the input voltage as is, or burn out, or output 0v.

I'm using the KA7808 with simple config, input pin directly connected to input voltage, Gnd pin connected to ground and measuring output voltage directly from output pin, no other passive component used. And I measured the output voltage at no load condition.

My questions are:

1. For the given circuit (see below) can we expect a Linear Voltage regulator to fail in a way that it generates a wrong output voltage which it is not rated for?
2. If answer to first question is 'yes', does it mean we should check every regulator for expected output voltage before using it in a circuit? I mean, do professionals do that as an 'always do' in everyday work where these regulators are used in large numbers?
3. This is not a yes/no question, but I was also looking for an explanation which might explain what could have caused the regulator to fail in this way, if the external circuitry supporting the Linear Regulator to work as expected, is correct. Can this be expected if any of the building blocks (the internal Error Amplifier, Thermal Protection, Current Generator, Series Pass Element etc) of the regulator fails? Or there is a chance of simple 'wrong labeling' by the manufacturer? (I thought, wrong labeling is impossible, because that is what an Electronics Professional would blindly believe in!)

Hope this clarifies my exact questions.

See the circuit diagram below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSfCls.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I think we should adopt the same attitude towards such questions as StackOverflow has regarding undefined behavior. If a device is faulty or used outside of spec, any guess regarding its behavior is as good as the other.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev - while the question is probably too broad to be a fit, you seem to be missing that the part is not *known* to be faulty.  Rather, the question is if this indicates that it *is* faulty.  Additionally, "undefined behavior" isn't nearly as meaningful a dodget in the world of physical devices - *how* things fail is often an extremely important design consideration.

Comment: @ChrisStratton The concept of "undefined behavior" is actually not that different for hardware. Does the datasheet describe possible failure modes of KA7808? If it does, that would be a valid answer, if not, it's pure guessing. There's no schematic so no way to disprove the OP's claim that the part is faulty, unless, as you said, I'm missing something.

Comment: Updated the question above with circuit diagram. I although do not understand the 3 comments posted above. I do claimed it faulty from a beginners standpoint, because it outputs wrong voltage. I will be more than happy to learn my mistake, if any.

Answer (score 5):

LM/KA78xx regulators are almost impossible to get to oscillate (unlike many other types such as LM1117, LM7905 etc). Others are either repeating folklore or are much (un)luckier in this regard than I have been (and I've tried to get them to ring).

We shipped approximately 30,000 units with no output capacitor, for example, and zero problems. And some 78xx datasheets explicitly state that the output capacitor is not required for stability. One of the advantages (along with price) of non-LDO positive regulators. Usually you want a cap on the output for transient response on a digital circuit, but typically nothing bad will happen other than poor regulation if you omit it. The internal voltage divider is more than sufficient minimum load at normal temperatures.

[image]

If the ground pin connection is not in place your output will go too high, so it's definitely not that.

You could have a defective part. You could have a (possibly fraudulently) remarked 7805. But, I **suspect** your problem is that you have a mains-frequency transformer followed by a rectifier and either no capacitor or insufficient capacitance. This is not a stability issue, but a filter capacitor/ripple voltage issue. if the input voltage is above about 9.5V you'll get 8V out, but if it dips down to say 3V, you'll get very little out, so the output would be a clipped version of the input waveform, plausibly with an average that was 4.8V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH9KZD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Comment: It seems that stability claim may depend on the maker though. According to the Fairchild datasheet, the output cap does improve stability. http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/308/fairchild%20semiconductor_ka7805ae-1191496.pdf Not that this answer is any less valid. Without more information and a scope picture, it's really all just speculation.

Comment: @Trevor. Never had any problem with Fairchild or NS or TI or ST in practice. One time many years ago (late 1980s) there was a massive shortage and the disty sourced some dubious parts from Eastern Europe. Some of those failed, but not by oscillation.

Comment: Yes indeed, I can't say I have ever had an issue with them either, though I never had to use them much. Mind you, that may have been because the rectifier cap and circuit caps were probably more than enough anyway. But, I just wanted to highlight the spec sheets say different things.

Comment: @Spehro I am suspecting this to be possible now 'You could have a (possibly fraudulently) remarked 7805'

Comment: Your answer was really useful. But I have a stable DC supply with a 4700uF filter cap. So at 18v output, ripples ranging as low as 9.5v or below is very less likely possible.

Comment: I have tried adding the capacitor as shown in your first circuit diagram. They didn't make any difference to the output voltage which is inline with your observation, so my doubt is it actually a 7805 but wrongly rated as 7808. Now, is that possible? I would be too afraid to hear yes.. :) Many a times we blindly apply them in circuits without measuring the output voltage, which can potentially damage other voltage sensitive expensive parts of the circuit.

Comment: @sribasu If you bought it from a franchised distributor the chances are close to zero. If you bought it from Aliexpress or eBay the chances are probably high single or double digit percent. Just got some fraudulently remarked chips .. as usual Ali won't do much.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany It was Ali... :(

Answer (score 3):

All these linear regulators require capacitors around them to keep them stable.

[image]

If you do not include those, the device will not operate as you expect.

See [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/229344/how-critical-are-the-input-and-out-capacitor-values-in-a-linear-voltage-regulato) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Trevor for the link. Is this unexpected behaviour almost certain? The same power supply unit has a KA7806 and a KA7805 in parallel to generate 6v and 5v outputs respectively. They are working just fine, without the cap

Comment: Bad idea @sribasu! Always always use bypass capacitors on both the input and output, or the IC WILL oscillate and output nothing but noise. Never skip the simple stuff.

Comment: Hi @Sparky256, following your "WILL oscillate and output nothing but noise" comment, please can you comment on Spehro's answer above as he's saying the complete opposite to that. I do find your claim an odd one. Thanks very much.

Comment: @sribasu I can't say whether it will oscillate for sure without the caps, but they are recommended and without them everything else is just a guess. However, if it does not work as you expect, the first thing to fix is to follow the manufacturers recommended usage, esp when it's just a matter of adding a couple of cheap capacitors. BTW. A scope will tell you far more than a meter with stuff like this.

Comment: @Trevor thanks for clarifying. I tried adding the caps and it didn't make any difference. I am more confused now, because I don't have a scope unfortunately.

Comment: @sribasu you really need to show us a full schematic of where and how you are generating the voltage going to the regulator and an indication of what, if anything, is attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

As Trevor suggested, the IC could be oscillatin.

Or the Iload is too high.

Or the input ripple is tool high.

Or Vin is too low.

Or the GND pin is not connected; with many of the internal circuits *needin* a path to GND or wild behaviors result, you need to ensure GND is indeed 0 volts.

Or the IC put itself into foldback protection, because the Cload is too high and the self-heating during powerup caused thermal overload and the part shutdown.

Comment: Thanks for response. There was no load when I measured the output. Faulty connection is very likely possible, I am expecting. I will still double check.

Comment: Some voltage regulators are unhappy when (1) there is no load, because the output power transistor (internal to silicon)enters a very poorly characterized region of operation, (2) the Cin or the Cout are not in place, or have wrong resistance internal to the capacitor, needed for proper phase/gain (BODE) shaping.

Comment: I rechecked the circuit and there was no connection error. I have practically used these linear regulators several times and measured correct output voltage at no load without any issue for almost everytime. So in my experience, even if Point #1 is theoritically  possible, but practically it doesn't.

Comment: And adding the capacitors at input and output pins of the regulator as suggested by you and mentioned in datasheet, didn't make any difference. I tried that and still reading the same  output voltage. My worst doubt is, the regulator is actually a 7805 but wrongly rated as KA7808... :(